# how to call my template and my function sequentially in xslt 2.0?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I am using xslt2.0 for convert one xml format to another xml format. This is my sample xml document.

```
<w:document>
    <w:body>
             <w:p>Para1</w:p> 
             <w:p>Para2</w:p> 
             <w:p>Para3</w:p> 
             <w:p>Para4</w:p> 
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Initially this is my xml format.so, i handled each and every `<w:p>` elements through my function in xslt given below...

```
 <xsl:template match="document">
      <Document>
    <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1,count(//w:body//w:p)-1)"/>
      </Document>    
</xsl:template>
```

So,In that xslt function, i have coded how to reformat those elements.It's working fine...

But now,Xml format is restructured like given below...

```
<w:document>
        <w:body>
                 <w:tbl><!--some text with children elements--></w:tbl>
                 <w:tbl><!--some text with children elements--></w:tbl>
                 <w:p>Para1</w:p> 
                 <w:p>Para2</w:p> 
                 <w:p>Para3</w:p> 
                 <w:p>Para4</w:p> 
        </w:body>
 </w:document>
```

So, As of now i have to handle both  and  elements in a same sequence.....

What i want to do is,

If i encounter  elemtents then i have to call my template given below...

```
<xsl:template match="document">
     <Document>
        <xsl:for-each select="w:tbl">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="w:tbl">
              </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1,count(//w:body//w:p)-1)"/>
     </Document>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:tbl">
<!--xslt code here -->
</xsl:template>
```

But the for-each statement is not executed when I trying transformation...

So, Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of

```
<xsl:template match="document">
     <Document>
        <xsl:for-each select="w:tbl">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="w:tbl">
              </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1,count(//w:body//w:p)-1)"/>
     </Document>    
</xsl:template>
```

you simply want

```
<xsl:template match="document">
     <Document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="w:body/w:tbl"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(body/p, 1,count(//w:body//w:p)-1)"/>
     </Document>    
</xsl:template>
```

If that does not do what you want then please show the result you want.

Comment: @ Martin Honnen: Thanks a lot Martin I am out of office now... I will check it and then let you know...

Comment: do you think both <w:tbl> elements will be executed in your code?

Comment: I have not properly set up the apply-templates but once I will do that in an edit then yes, any `tbl` will be processed.

Comment: I have edited the code, if the `document` element is the matched node in the template and the `tbl` are children of the `body` in the document then of course the path needs to be `w:body/w:tbl`.

Comment: Thanks Martin i tested...It is working in right way...But what i want to do is First i have to check the first child of <w:body>.If it is <w:tbl> then i have to call my template(named w:tbl)by selecting only the first<w:tbl> of <w:body> (not entire w:body/w:tbl, i mean only w:body/w:tbl[0]).Otherwise i just want to call my function that handle <w:p> elements...

Comment: With XPath the first index in a sequence is `1` not `0` so to select the first `w:tbl` child element of the `w:body` you simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select="w:body/w:tbl[1]"/>`. If you want to check whether the first child element of the `w:body` element is a `w:tbl` then use `<xsl:choose><xsl:when test="w:body/*[1][self::w:tbl]">...`. You might however better start a new question where you clearly state the requirements in the post.